# Multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline

I'm working on a history calculator in which I want the last line of my `EditText` to move up after each click on the equal button. Is this possible? I set the following code in the main xml

```
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="false" 
        android:lines="5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
```

Comment: 2+5 is being performed in the last line of the EditText, now when i click the equal button .. the 2+5 should move at the top line of editText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on click event of equals button just have this code

```
edittext.setText(edittext.getText()+"\n"+your_result_of_calculation);
```

Comment: It does not work. How to refer to each line is the question. We only have one EditText object.

Comment: String[] result = edittext.getText().toString().split("\n");  Use this to get a string array of all the lines

Answer (score 0):

Uh ! As per your requirement, I think you can do it by appendin ' \n ' to the existing text.

Comment: This would remove the last line, no? Maybe remove the first line?